# Apache w/out internet connection

Tags: apache-http-server, internet-connection

I have a Vista laptop that I have been running Apache / MySql / Php / PhpMyAdmin on for quite some time without fail.  I just use it to test bits of code here and there etc.  No problems, until recently when I needed to test something and I happened to be in a place that I could not get an internet connection.  Why am I unable to access localhost from the same machine without an internet connection?  I am type http://localhost..etc into the browser's address bar and I get the message that I am unable to access without an internet connection.  I checked my windows/system32/etc/hosts file and the first two lines are

127.0.0.1   localhost

::1         localhost

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the server up? Have you checked?

Comment: Do you mean `http://localhost/etc`? (`/`, not `..`)

Comment: Why do you have localhost in your hosts file twice? There should only be one entry that is `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: @James Goodwin - "::1 localhost" is for IPv6

Comment: Do you use http://localhost/ when you have internet plugged in, or just when you are not connected? If so, then the problem most likely is a wrongly configured NameVirtualHost directive.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to stick a loopback Ethernet plug into your ethernet port?

http://www.tikkiweb.net/loopback

http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/tools/6c20/

Comment: This is not required to access localhost from a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a problem with the browser. If you are on Firefox and there is no internet connection it will put you into "offline mode". Check this by going to File > Work Offline

Comment: It happens with both Mozilla and IE...  Oh and Opera too.

Comment: this seems most likely to me, assuming the OP's URL is misreported :)

Comment: The tcp/ip stack with loopback is started along with the configured network connection in many versions of windows.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the Apache server is not running or you have the port configured to a different port on your machine.

Another potential issue is that the host name of apache may be different than 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once on an older version of windows, where I needed to dial up to make the loopback (127.0.0.1) work.

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Install-Microsoft-Loopback-adapter-Windows-XP.html

You should be able to install a loopback adapter (software driver as described in the article above), but you might consider get a router and make your own little development network instead.